# Connecting semi-spheres to a model

Tags: modeling

[image: Wireframe view]

[image: You can see the semi-sphere don't connect when the model is sibdivided]

Whilst on the topic, how could I make this model more game-ready overall? I'm doing this to just practice.

Answer (score 0):

As for spheres - remove bottom halves that are inside geometry and then just attach using <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to join it with the main mesh.
As for game ready - one idea would be to actually bake the spheres as a normal texture and use it to imitate bumpiness.

For gameready object i would not use subsurface modifier at all, instead I would make a denser model with subsurf (like one you have already), and then I would retopo it - using shrinkwrap modifier  I would create a low-detail version.

Comment: personally, rather than having the spheres be geometry, I'd sculpt them on, and then bake the sculpt detail as a bump map.